# Using $localStorage inside the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Description:

I have a user information screen where we get user details and store it in the DB when `save` is selected (this is activated only once). Im using `$localStorage` in my controller in-order to hold the data entered by the user,so that when app is closed and opened the same information exists. And also when the information are edited the changes should be seen in the settings and also get stored in both the DB and also in `$localStorage`.

Problem:

when I try to save the data Im getting error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $localStorageProvider <- $localStorage <- revenue-management-controller`. This the first time Im try using the `$localStorage`, Im not sure if Im using it right. Im trying to use two `$localStorage`, one to store the data during `save` action. Another one during `update` action. So please help in this.

Html:

```
Name:
<input type="text ng-model="name">
DOB:
<input type="date" ng-model="dob">
Area of Interest:
<input type="text" ng-model="interest">

<button type="submit" ng-click="Add()">Add</button>
<button type="submit" ng-click="update()">Update</button>
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('userInfo', function ($scope, $state, $localStorage, userDataManagement) {

        $scope.Add = function () {
            var userData = {'name': $scope.name, 'dob': $scope.dob, 'interest': $sope.interest};
            $localStorage.savedInfo = userData;
            userDataManagement.postData(userData, error);
        };
        $scope.update = function () {
            var userData2 = {'name': $scope.name, 'dob': $scope.dob, 'interest': $scope.interest};
            $localStorage.updateInfo = userData2;
            userDataManagement.postData(userData2, error)
        };
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:

This error is always thrown in case you miss the dependency. This [Click Here](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) is the module you must add to use `$localstorage`. Take a look at the module and  syntax.

or you can use `$window.localStorage`, make sure `$window` is in the argument section.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install and add the localstorage module to your project correctly: 
https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/js/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
    ...
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['LocalStorageModule']);

    </script>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

after that you can install $localstorage in your controller liket this:
set a value:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {
  //...
  function submit(key, val) {
   return localStorageService.set(key, val);
  }
  //...
});
```

get a value:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {
  //...
  function getItem(key) {
   return localStorageService.get(key);
  }
  //...
});
```

so for your controller it would be something like this:

```
myApp.controller('userInfo',function($scope, $state, localStorageService, userDataManagement){

       $scope.Add=function(){
             var userData={'name':$scope.name, 'dob':$scope.dob, 'interest':$sope.interest};
             localStorageService.set("savedInfo",userData);
           userDataManagement.postData(userData,error);
};
         $scope.update=function(){
             var userData2 = {'name':$scope.name, 'dob':$scope.dob, 'interest':$scope.interest);
            localStorageService.set("updateInfo", userData2;
            userDataManagement.postData(userData2,error);
              };
})
```

Comment: I have used `LocalStorageModule` but still same error exist. can you give working code so understanding will be easy.

Comment: @jazzoria I added an edited verision of your code to my answer.